# How to start getting into trading?

Tags: stocks, investing, trading, stock-markets

Investing money using stocks is kind of confusing. Since I plan to invest a lot of money (edit: I don't have a lot of money, I mean that relative to my other savings), I need to know what I do in every aspect, since I want to understand what I do completely.

**Is there any good resource, where you get the starter-questions answered?**

I find close to nothing for a beginner and most resources only cover some cases where you already need some knowledge.

It starts with simple things like: "I want to invest in Nintendo, but when I search for it, I get like 20 results?!"

Comment: Buying Nintendo stock is pretty straightforward - what part confuses you?  Open a account with a broker like eTrade, Fidelity, etc. and start buying stocks.  If you truly have "a lot" of money, then look for a financial advisor (not to pick stocks, but to teach you about different types of investments).

Comment: I suggest you explain why opening a brokerage account, depositing a lot of money, and buying the stock you wish, isn't as simple as we think it should be. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Is it really simple as that? Where are the pitfalls (for example: trading costs which the bank takes, and so on)? Why are there like 20 Nintendo Brands listed if there is only one company called Nintendo? I can't really tell what specifically the question is. I just wonder if there is a detailed "getting started" guide or something like that that explains the aspects of trading. I know how the system is supposed to work, but that's like knowing where energy comes from, without knowing how it actually is produced.

Comment: Hopefully you mean "investing" rather than "trading". Do some reading at https://www.bogleheads.org/. In particular, https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Getting_started and this PDF is free: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29031758/If%20You%20Can.pdf

Comment: Part of our issue here is the level of detail we have or are missing. I pull up a [Nintendo Quote](https://finance.yahoo.com/chart/NTDOY) pretty easily, and can only guess why you see multiple tickers. But that's not the topic of the question subject line. It appears you are really asking "I'd like to invest, where do I start." That's ok, but we can't answer just yet. I'd linger here and read all the questions that are tagged 'stock' or 'investing', then ask the specific questions that may follow.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Thanks, I'm currently reading the PDF. :) Taxpayer: I know, it's very vague what I'm asking here. Good tip, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Trading and investing are very, very different activities.

Investing is (very generally) done for the longer haul, by people looking for a reasonable return, determined largely by the long term prospects of the business in which they invest, accepting some moderate risk, usually around the prospects of that business.

Trading is (very generally) done shorter term (seconds to days/weeks), and can involve significantly higher risk, usually focused around market conditions and players at the time of the trade.

To reiterate, these are gross generalizations, but if you are just starting out:  (a) you probably want to be investing, rather than trading; and (b) you may be best served by understanding as well as you can the difference between the two.  Once you understand that difference, that will lead you to learning resources on each.